# Pycharm: Sharing run configurations across platforms

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to share PyCharm run configurations across multiple machines and platforms by storing them under version control. However, I have noticed that the run configuration XML file contains platform-**dependent** information, namely the full path of the python interpreter:

```
File .idea/runConfigurations/job.xml:
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="job_name" type="tests" factoryName="Nosetests">
    ...
    <option name="SDK_HOME" value="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python" />
    ...
  </configuration>
</component>
```

How can I share my run configurations without keeping the full python interpreter path around?

Comment: I had a slightly related problem and found this issue, which was that I didn't have a _runConfigurations_ directory even though I had several items. By default they seem to be stored in _workspace.xml_. You have to go to "Edit configurations..." and tick a checkbox for each configuration you want to save and they will end up in that dir.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722287/how-does-one-share-only-the-deployment-configurations-in-pycharm-across-pych

Comment: is this the same as deployment configurations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying it out, it turns out that the `SDK_HOME` field doesn't need to have a value, as long as the project has a python interpreter set: `<option name="SDK_HOME" value="" />`

To remove a given interpreter from all job files:

```
sed -i -e 's#SDK_HOME" value=".*"#SDK_HOME" value=""#g' *xml
```

Setting the project's python interpreter does change `misc.xml` and `semantic-planning.iml`, but presumably these could be ignored from version control.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a symlink with the same name to the local interpreter on each machine. That's neither neat nor scalable, but it has worked well for me. I regularly use four machine (2 Linux, 2 OSX) and it took all of 1 minute to create the appropriate symlinks. Should also work on Windows (mklink) but I haven't tried it myself.